# Coroutines getting and setting a theme on an activity

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, datastore

How would I set the theme of an activity before it is created, when the theming information must be retrieved from DataStore?

Since the data needs to come immediately, a runBlocking has been necessary. Can I work around using a runBlocking in this case?

Example:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    runBlocking {
        val theme = settingsRepository.getTheme()
        this@ThemedActivity.setTheme(theme)
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

Comment: You tried this code without `runBlocking` and it failed?

Comment: Since I am using DataStore, the `getTheme()` function is suspending. It must be run in a scope.

Comment: what about viewModel scope? It runs on Main by default, so I think you can control the theme from the viewmodel

Comment: @Sterix, that can't solve the requirement to set the theme before `super.onCreate` is called.

Comment: @Knossos, you can prefetch data in a coroutine, perhaps in your Application class. Then if you use `runBlocking` in your Activity, it is likely to run faster than an initial fetch would, because I think DataStore caches value to memory after first loading it from disk. You could also insert an intermediate blank screen activity to stall for time, maybe?

Comment: @Tenfour04 
Would not it be working if super.onCreate runs on UI thread? Calling method of a viewmodel, which runs the logic in the viewmodel scope (also UI thread by default)

Comment: @Tenfour04 I could try loading it in the application class. The problem is there is no guarantee it is finished by the time the theme needs to be set (due to the async nature of the datastore).

Steyrix It would run on the UI thread, that is true. However, it is still a launched coroutine, and it would finish after the super call.

Comment: @Steyrix, the Activity class breaks if it returns from `onCreate()` without calling `super.onCreate()`. If you call it from a coroutine, `onCreate()` will have returned before the coroutine is finished.

Comment: @Knossos, yes, there is no guarantee. That's why I suggested the possibility of an intermediate activity. But if your data store is relatively small, it will load so fast that you don't need to worry so much about using `runBlocking` in `onCreate()`.